# Possible to get rid of internal lines of two or more regions adjacent to each other to form one whole region

Tags: google-api, kml, google-earth

As the title says, is it possible to get rid of internal lines of two or more regions (placemarks in KML file) adjacent to each other to form one whole region for google earth to display?

I hope I explained clear enough.

Comment: Are these KMLs showing imagery or something? Can you provide a sample?